# Session Funda of destroying a specific session

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I am working on Visual Stdio 2008 and my database is in sql server 2005 
I am Storing Data in session.
i have

```
Session["FisrstName"]
Session["SecondName"]
Session["LastName"]
```

i just want that only `Session["LastName"]` should be destoryed 
how can i achieve this ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the contents to null.

```
Session["LastName"] = null;
```